# Reference with custom name and foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, rails-migrations, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm on Rails 5 and have a `User` model.

I want to create a `Book` model, referencing the `User` model with the name `author`. I want as well to set foreign keys in the migration.

When searching an answer I have only found how to *add* columns in a migration, not on creating a new table. How would the below look like for `create_table :books`?

```
add_reference :books, :author, references: :users, index: true
add_foreign_key :books, :users, column: :author_id
```

Comment: Tips: don't forget the dependent :destroy or nullify and add an index on this column. (I have edited my answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use 
    author_id:integer

Then in your User model:

```
has_many :books, foreign_key: :author_id, class_name: "Book", dependent: :nullify
```

I use dependent: :nullify to avoid errors when you delete a record, but you can use dependent: :destroy if you need to destroy the books when you destroy the user.

And Book model:

```
belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :author_id, class_name: 'User'
```

You should add an index on this column.